# Is there any way to use authentication service without azure bot service?

Tags: c#, azure, bots

I am using bot framework v4 ,is it necessary to use azure bot service  for AAd(Azure active directory) to get authenticated in bot?

Answer (score 1):

No, it is based on which channel you want to use. For instance, if you use a custom WebChat channel, you can auth users first on the web page and then use tokens based on your bot business logic. [This is a great demo for it](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/19.b.single-sign-on-for-intranet-apps/).

What's more , though it is not recommended, [Azure AD ROPC flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) will work for all channels by Azure AD rest API or Azure AD SDK to auth users.
As you need to require your users to input their username and passwords in this flow while your bot interacting with users, which will carry risks are not present in other flows. You should only use this flow when other more secure flows can't be used.

Hope it helps.

Comment: i want to deploy my bot on Teams, is it necessary to host bot in azure bot service? i have created bot in c#.net and i have deployed my bot on gadday  and was trying to connect that bot with bot emulator but it is not working, Is it necessary to use azure bot service

Comment: @teju1 Of course, to avoid unexcepted exceptions, you should host your bot code on Azure bot service for your production environment.

Comment: I believe the collection of demos in your first link has moved here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/07.advanced-web-chat-apps