# How to implement OAuth flow in Bot without using OAuthPrompt Dialog for unsupported channels such as Zoom and WebEx

Tags: botframework, bots

I have an existing bot code that uses OAuthPrompt dialog that I would like to deploy for Zoom and WebEx that are not supported by Azure Bot Service. As per the documentation and sample code, I have used the adapter for supporting those channels. It works fine. But it does not support OAuthPrompt Dialog, it returns "OAuthPrompt.BeginDialog(): not supported by the current adapter".

When I debugged with the source code (Bot builder SDK /w Adapter), Implementation of OAuthPrompt dialog checks whether adapter implements IExtendedUserTokenProvider interface, currently it is not, so it returns error. How to add OAuth card support without using OAuthPrompt Dialog/Azure Bot Service?

This question is similar to mine:
([Is there any way to use authentication service without azure bot service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59496243/is-there-any-way-to-use-authentication-service-without-azure-bot-service))
Following are my thoughts:

1. Directly send a request to identity provider with redirect URL (my bot endpoint) for OAuth2 code flow. Also update the redirect URI in the App Registration portal with bot endpoint, currently I have provided Redirect URI as "https://token.botframework.com/.auth/web/redirect" for supported channels.
2. Implement the IExtendedUserTokenProvider in the adapter (similar to Emulator).

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Update: I went with hybrid approach including option 1 and 2 and extended OAuthPrompt dialog (SignInCard is not supported in Zoom)  and Adapter class where it implements IExtendedUserTokenProvider and started the authentication code grant flow and got the auth code and redeem the auth code with access token, now figuring out the generation of magic code (verification code). This link is very helpful (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot).

Answer (score 0):

I can get it working by having customized OAuthPrompt dialog for Zoom, implementing IExtendedUserTokenProvider in ZoomAdapter (ZoomAdapterWIthErrorHandler). OAuth connection settings (such as identity server endpoint, scopes, redirect uri} are stored in the appSettings.json for the connection name. Supported channels (MS Teams and Slack) will use the SDK provided implementation (OAuthPrompt Dialog) with settings from ConnectionName configured in the Azure, unsupported channels will get the settings from the AppSettings.json file. GetSignInResourceAsync() should have the right implementation that returns the sign-in resource Uri.