# How to implement OAuth flow in Bot without using OAuthPrompt Dialog for unsupported channels such as Zoom

Tags: azure, oauth, botframework

I'm aiming to use Azure Web app bot within Zoom Client. I'm strugling a little bit with the Authentication part.
The [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66231311/how-to-implement-oauth-flow-in-bot-without-using-oauthprompt-dialog-for-unsuppor) suggested a implementation of IExtendedUserTokenProvider to use Custom Channels.
Can someone explain me further this? How can I intercept the *new OAuthCard* and use my own token implementation?

Comment: is your issue resolved?